# undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have the following test program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;    
pthread_mutex_t mymutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int iret;
  iret = pthread_mutex_trylock( & mymutex );
  cout << "Test2 !!! " << endl;
  pthread_mutex_unlock( & mymutex );
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If I compile it without adding the pthread library I get the error for unresolved error for pthread_mutex_trylock , but only for function pthread_mutex_trylock.

If I replace pthread_mutex_trylock with pthread_mutex_trylock the program is compiled and runnig well also without the -lpthread* option.

If I add the -lpthraed option to the compile commands all runs well
this run well         :   **$ g++ test2.c -o test2 -lpthread**
this warn unresolved  :   **$ g++ test2.c -o test2**

Example error output: 
    $ g++ test2.c -o test2
    /tmp/ccU1bBdU.o: In function `main':
    test2.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to`pthread_mutex_trylock'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

If I replace the instruction **iret = pthread_mutex_trylock( & mymutex );**

with **iret = pthread_mutex_lock( & mymutex );** the program compiles and run without error also if didn't add the pthread libarry to the compile command
I know that is right to have the unresolved error if I didn't use the -lpthread option , but why I have not the same unresolved error also for other pthread_ function ?

I'm using gcc 4.4.2 on fedora 12

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.2 20091222 (Red Hat 4.4.2-20)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Do some have some suggestion about the meaning of this unreference only for pthread_mutex_trylock  ?

thanks for the help, Enzo

Comment: That might be some platform-specific behaviour, but why do you even bother? You are supposed to link with pthread, just do it.

Comment: mybe I have still the will to learn :)

Comment: Nevertheless this question is useful in a situation like mine, where a call to `pthread_mutex_lock()` was replaced by `pthread_mutex_trylock()` causing things to break for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use pthread functions you should link your object files with `-lpthread` and not worry about whether symbols are included in `libc`.

The rationale behind this is [said](http://mail.opensolaris.org/pipermail/opensolaris-code/2009-February/006691.html) to be such: some time ago the stubs in libc were used when application that used threads was run on a system without threading support.  On such system, `pthread_*` functions became linked to `libc` stubs that returned errors showing that there's no threading functionality.  While on "threaded" systems they were linked to `pthread` library and worked correctly.

Obviously, `pthread_mutex_trylock` function appeared after the policy changed to linking with `-lpthread`.  So there's no stub for it.

Comment: thank Pavel, now this strange behaviour i smore clear.

regars, ebzo

Comment: BTW, `-lpthread` is not portable, and in particular, older versions of BSD used `libc_r`, not `libpthread`. Thus, `-pthread` is more portable and recommended.

Answer (score 15):

You should perform both the compilation and linkage with the `-pthread` option, to be portable. On some systems, the compilation will have specific flags added (e.g., `-D_REENTRANT`) with `-pthread` specified.

If you're curious to see what `-pthread` will do to your compile and link flags, run `gcc -dumpspecs`.